# GPG: secret key & check passphrase

Tags: ruby, security, shell, gnupg, pgp

How to check that GPG **secret** key does not contain passphrase?
I wouldn't like import this key.

Comment: Sorry, actually, you should post your answer. You can accept your own answer after 24? hrs, by doing the check-mark thing, and this will increase your reputation points.

Comment: > whathaveyoutried.com - looks good.
Thanks for your time)

Comment: ok, glad that helped your thinking. Note my revised comments. You can post your solution as an answer and gain reputation points. ALSO, in the future, your code makes it clear you using something that is not a shell as your main language. Using the correct tags `[python]` or ??? will greatly improve the number of "eyes" that are looking at your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3("echo '\n\n\n\n\nsave' | gpg --command-fd 0 --homedir #{dir} --edit-key #{secret_key[:keyid]} passwd")
output = stderr.read
if output =~ /.../
  ...
end
```